# Python list insertion run time complexity

Tags: python, insert, time-complexity

I know that inserting to list is `O(n)` since the worst case is insert to index `0`.

Now my question is, what if we let `A`, `B` be lists such that `len(A) = len(B) = N` and we're trying to insert into `A` each element from `B` in that way:

```py
A[0:0] = B
```

Is it going to take `O(N^2)`?

Comment: What did you find when you measured it for different values of N?

Comment: No, it is going to be O(N)

Comment: Why actually? The original memory id of A isn't changed as a result of this operation, hence I deduce that all the previous elements have been moved N steps, N times.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand about how lists work in Python, using slicing to copy an list doesn't actually perform any insertions, it just replaces the element at every index in A with the element at the same index in B. It will take `O(n)` time because it's essentially performing a linear scan of list A, but with the additional step of assigning a new value to each index, which itself takes `O(1)` for each assignment.

On a side note, `A[0:0] = B` will not copy list B's contents into list A unless A is an empty list, i.e., `A = []`. Otherwise, the contents of B are prepended onto A, causing A to be of length 2N instead of N as is desired. This itself will take $O(n^2)$ because it essentially performs insertions of the worst case scenario for every element of list B.

If you want to overwrite any content inside list A by copying the contents of list B, I'd suggest the following:

```
A = B[:]
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, [this GeeksforGeeks article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-cloning-copying-list/#:%7E:text=3.-,List%20copy%20using%20%3D(assignment%20operator),new%20list%20using%20assignment%20operators.) lists quite a few different ways to copy a list into another.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected to be linear (`O(n)`), but here is the experimental check (2 to 10^8 items, 100 runs each except the last 3 points (only 20)):

[image]

*NB. there is non-negligible overhead for the first few points, likely due to constant operations (slicing, assignment).*

Each point is calculated using `timeit`:

```
n = 10 # number or items in list, to make variable in a loop
r = 100 # or 20
t = {}
t[n] = timeit('A[0:0] = B', number=r,
              setup=f'A = list(range({n})) ; B = list(range({n}))'
              )/r
```